# Git. Update untracked files

Tags: git, git-add

When I use command `git add -u .` git still doesn't update untracked files.
Works only when I specify them by path, `git add -- filepath`
What could it be?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

*untracked* files cannot be *updated*. they are not tracked in the first place.
you need to **add** untracked files. to do that most commonly you'd use:

```
$ git add some_untracked_file
$ # or
$ git add .  # add all files
$ # or
$ git add --all # similar to -A , add all again
```

*all* there doesnt mean every file, but every file that doesn't match an entry in the *.gitignore* file.

from the man page:

> ```
>   -u, --update
>       Only match <filepattern> against already tracked files in the index rather than the working tree. That means that it will never stage
>       new files, but that it will stage modified new contents of tracked files and that it will remove files from the index if the
>       corresponding files in the working tree have been removed.
>
>       If no <filepattern> is given, default to "."; in other words, update all tracked files in the current directory and its
>       subdirectories.
>
>   -A, --all
>       Like -u, but match <filepattern> against files in the working tree in addition to the index. That means that it will find new files as
>       well as staging modified content and removing files that are no longer in the working tree.
> ```

Comment: $ git add . - doesn't add untracked files.

Comment: as I said `git add .` and `git add -A` both add all _untracked_ files, that do not match an entry in `.gitignore` file. You can test that easily: `mkdir test; cd test; touch a b c; git init; git add a; git commit -m "add a"; echo "b" > .gitignore; git add .gitignore; git commit -m "add ignore"; git add .; git commit -m "add c";` _b_ is ignored and not added by `git add .` or `git add -A` because it matches an entry in _.gitignore_.

Answer (score 2):

See git manual:

> -u, --update
>   Only match  against **already tracked** files in the index rather than he working tree. That means that it will never
>   stage new files, but that it will stage modified new contents of
>   tracked files and that it will remove files from the index if the
>   corresponding files in the working tree have been removed.